# Spring Boot 1.5: accept "multipart/*" in file upload

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, spring-boot, apache-commons-fileupload

My Spring Boot 1.5.1 + Commons Fileupload 1.3.2 file upload request mapping fails with `multipart/form-data`. My request mapping look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/api/users/uploads")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> uploadUsers(
    @RequestParam(value="file", required=true) MultipartFile file
    ) throws IOException {
    String uploadFilename = file.getName();

    try(InputStream input = file.getInputStream()) {
        usersConverter.read(input);
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok("Uploaded " + uploadFilename + " successfully.");
}
```

with a `curl`:

```
curl -v -u 'username:password'
     -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed"
     -X POST -F file=@users.csv
     http://localhost:8080/api/users/uploads
```

works fine:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'username'
> POST /api/users/uploads HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Authorization: Basic cGFzc3dvcmQ=
> User-Agent: curl/7.42.1
> Content-Length: 8237
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=-------------------4c6cae60d33268be
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=8F80A63F1B83982DA1614ADD7BCB6C16;path=/;HttpOnly
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 27
< Date: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 17:39:51 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

but I have some clients which send `multipart/form-data` instead of `multipart/mixed` and I'd like this request mapping to handle both. I've tried adding the following to the `@RequestMapping`:

- `consumes="multipart/*"`
- `consumes={"multipart/mixed", "multipart/form-data"`
- `headers="content-type=multipart/*"`
- `headers={"content-type=multipart/mixed", "content-type=multipart/form-data"}`

but in each case:

```
curl -v -u 'username:password'
     -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
     -X POST -F file=@users.csv
     http://localhost:8080/api/users/uploads
```

fails with a `400`:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'username'
> POST /api/users/uploads HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Authorization: Basic cGFzc3dvcmQ=
> User-Agent: curl/7.42.1
> Content-Length: 8237
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-------------------85d8a22839d9bc08
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 400 
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1EB31D866907E49F0972F601E22317D0;path=/;HttpOnly
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 17:42:00 GMT
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

My Angular 2.4 client which sends `multipart/form-data` fails with (presumably the same) `400`.

Any ideas how I get the request mapping to handle `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: Try check this link [spring upload file](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/curl-post-request-examples/). Maybe your curl is wrong.

Comment: @MatejMarconak -- the `curl` command appears to be correct; it works with `mixed` but not with `form-data` -- that's the only difference between the two. And in both cases, `curl` adds the required `boundary` value. And I get the same `400` from non-`curl` client which supply `form-data` instead of `mixed`.

Comment: 400: BAD REQUEST - can you try call from js, because spring definition looks ok

Comment: See my updated question, @MatejMarconak -- JS client fail similarly.

Comment: Try change parameters for method to - HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response and then check what looks like request ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh - it's a bug. Remove `commons-fileupload` and `commons-io` dependencies:

```
  <!-- 
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
   <version>2.4</version>
  </dependency>
  -->
```

and remove `multipartResolver` bean definition:

```
    /*
    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(100000);

        return multipartResolver;
    }
    */
```

then the request mapping works for both `multipart/mixed` and `multipart/form-data` as expected...and my Angular client works, too.